# Is there a way to define a RabbitMQ consumer that keeps listening for a queue without blocking the program?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am working on project, using RabbitMq in python. Initially an Admin Verify an order which is then published in a RabbitMq message queue 'verified_orders', I want to have a consumer that keeps listening for this MQ , consume an order and send it back with details to the client, but without blocking the state of the whole program.

I have seen RabbitMQ tutorials in which I found this code
Suppose that the connection to the RabbitMQ is already established

Code to publish messages

```
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='verified_orders',
                      body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
```

Code to Consume

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(f" [x] Received {body}")

channel.basic_consume(queue='verified_orders',
                      auto_ack=True,
                      on_message_callback=callback)

channel.start_consuming()
```

When executing start_consuming() it will infinitely waits for data and runs callbacks, however the program will enter a blocking state which I am trying to avoid.

Another approach that I found is to define an async function with an infinite loop to consume messages, but I don't believe that it is a good approach to use infinite loop.

```
channel.basic_get(queue='verified_orders', auto_ack=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-blocking program, you must use concurrency. There are two ways to implement it, one is using `multi-threading` and the other is `asynchronous programming`.

The Async method is much more optimal because you can achieve your goal by using an infinite loop inside a single thread. Also you use `async` when you have an IO bound task and connecting, consuming from or publishing to a MQ is an IO bound task.

As I understood from your code sample, you are using the [`pika`](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library. This library is implemented as sync. You can use [`aiopika`](https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead, which provides all the features of `Rabbitmq` as async.